# How to: add my Anchor wallet to Phantom

Tags: anchor, phantom, private-key

How can I export my Anchor's private key in order to import it on Phantom.

```
solana config get
```

Displays a `Keypair Path` but I'm not sure how to turn the byte array within into my private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phantom accetps the array as a Private key.

Just copy the contents of the `id.json` and paste it in the import private key in Phantom.

Answer (score 1):

Found on the [deep coffins of reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/solana/comments/q5daki/comment/ikoui8i/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

That `id.json` file on the `Keypair Path` indeed holds your private key.

To export it, the following terminal commands suffices:

```
cat <Keypair file path>
# copy the result and:
python -c "print(bytes(<paste the array here>).hex())"
```

Now in phantom, click on your account icon, browse into `your accounts`, select the `import private key` option and paste the result from the python command there.

Finally, to verify everything went as planned, switch to the `devnet` within phantom, run:

```
solana airdrop 1 
# or 
solana airdrop 1 <your public key> --url devnet
```

And check the transaction on your phantom wallet.